# T = { $\alpha : f(\alpha) = 0 $} and S = { $\alpha: g(\alpha) = 0 $ } then T $\bigcap$ S =?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

$T = \{ \alpha \mid f(\alpha) = 0 \}$ and $S = \{ \alpha \mid g(\alpha) = 0  \}$ then $T \cap S =$ ?

(a) $f(\alpha)+g(\alpha) = 0$

(b) $f^2(\alpha)+g^2(\alpha) = 0$

(c) $f(\alpha)-g(\alpha) = 0$

(d) $f(\alpha)g(\alpha) = 0$

Attempt: $T \cap S$ implies the points where both $f$ and $g$ become $0$. Hence

$T \cap S = \{ \alpha \mid \text{$f(\alpha) =0$ and $g(\alpha) = 0$} \}$

Hence, (a), ( b), (c), (d) all must be correct.

But the only correct answer given is (b). Where could i be mistaken ?
Thanks

Comment: $f^2(\alpha)+g^2(\alpha)=0$ implies $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: @ALGEAN, that may depend on what sets are $\;f,g\;$ defined, and this isn't given...real, complex, finite fields...?

Comment: yeah, this is a question from real analysis. So, must be a real field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question isn't asking which statements are true for $\alpha\in T\cap S$ (they all are). It is asking which statement(s) *characterize* the members of $T \cap S$. That is, you want $\alpha\in T\cap S$ if and only if the statement is true.

For example,  (d) is wrong because, even though all members of the set satisfy (d), so do any points that are zeroes of just *one* of $f$ or $g$.

So which one of these conditions guarantees that $f(\alpha)$ and $g(\alpha)$ are both zero *at the same time*?

Answer (score 2):

You can have 
$$f(\alpha)+g(\alpha) = 0,\qquad f(\alpha)-g(\alpha) = 0,\qquad f(\alpha)g(\alpha) = 0$$ **with**
$$f(\alpha)\ne 0\qquad{\rm or}\qquad g(\alpha)\ne 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Well suppose $g = -f$. Then $f(\alpha) - g (\alpha) = 0$ for all $\alpha$ so a can not be correct.

For c: Suppose $f= g$ then again $f - g = 0$ for all $\alpha$, so c cannot be correct

For d: if $f(\alpha) = 0$ and $g(\alpha) \neq 0$ it still holds that $f(\alpha)*g(\alpha)=0$ so $d$ cannot be correct.

Now for b: Look at it this way the only way $f^2(\alpha) = 0 $ is if $f(\alpha) =0$. The same holds for $g^2$. This means that $f^2(\alpha) + g^2(\alpha) = 0$ if and only if $f(\alpha)=0$ and $g(\alpha) = 0$. So answer b satisfies the criterium you have found.

Answer (score 2):

It must not only be true that $f\left(\alpha\right)=g\left(\alpha\right)=0$ implies the statement under a),b),c)
or d). Also the opposite must be true. If e.g. statement a) is true can
you then conclude that $f\left(\alpha\right)=g\left(\alpha\right)=0$?

Answer (score 2):

a) includes points $\alpha$ where $0 \neq f(\alpha) = - g(\alpha)$.

c) includes points $\alpha$ where $0 \neq f(\alpha) = g(\alpha)$.

d) includes points $\alpha$ where $f(\alpha)$ or $g(\alpha)$ is equal to zero, but not necessarily both at the same time.